# How to set the india time in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, datetime, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2

I want to save the India time in our created field can anyone help me how to do that. What type of setting I have to do that when user registers? I want the India time to be stored on created_at field. Like in whatsapp chat you saw that when we chat in India it will display the India timings when we chat.

Here is my Code:

```
$current = Carbon::now();
$current = new Carbon();
$today = Carbon::today();
```

but it returns me UK time date.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Go to `your_project/config/app.php`, there is a line:

```
'timezone' => ''
```

set it to:

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

It will set the default timezone to `Asia/Kolkata`. After setting this you will get Indian time.

Here is the list of [Supported Timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Comment: Its better to set these in `.env` file and use that in `app.php`
`date_default_timezone_set(env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'UTC'));`

Answer (score 2):

```
$var  = Carbon::now('Asia/Kolkata');
return $time = $var->toTimeString();
```

I had the same issue. The above code is working fine for me. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code to set timezone in laravel

```
config(['app.timezone' => 'Asia/Kolkata']);
```